# Regularize variables for Johansen coinegration

Tags: normalization, standardization, cointegration

I am looking into applying the Johansen cointegration procedure to variables of very different scales, going from units to tens of thousands. I use log(prices) but the scale difference is still very large, plus variable with values < 1 become negative.
I am wondering what's the best approach to deal with this issue. If I don't scale the variables the cointegrating vector will give a huge weight to the variable with a high scale.

What's the best practice to deal with this issue ?

Comment: The log transformation might still do the job, unless the transformed negative values are very large. Do not worry about the sign (i.e. some values becoming negative); there is nothing wrong with that. Also, if you do not scale the variables, the cointegrating vector will most likely have a *tiny* (not huge) weight on the variable with a large scale.

Comment: Noted, the cointegrating vector will have a tiny weight on variable with a large scale. I was wondering if using a measure of long term variance to scale the variables (something like new_data = data/data.expanding(min_periods=21, center=None, axis=1).std()) would make more sense, as I would preserve the time series structure and put variables on an equal scale with no negative values. Would this method be superior to log prices for the purpose of Johansen cointegration ?

Comment: Perhaps. You could try that.